# Do not show fiddler error message when dns is not found

Tags: web, proxy, fiddler

I you fiddler core to monitor web traffic from the browser. However I have a problem when website does not exist. Fiddler then displays custom error message that website do not exist. I would like to display the standard error message from the browser... Maybe somebody knows how to do that?

Regards,
Andrzej

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that "You can't pretend like a proxy isn't there" when it really is. Having said that, the reason you see the Fiddler error message is because I deliberately pad the response body out to 512 bytes so that the error message is shown instead of IE's Friendly error message. If you'd instead like to show a different error message (including one shorter than 256 bytes to ensure that the client gets the browser's "Friendly" error page if that option is configured, you can do so by intercepting the `FiddlerApplication.BeforeReturningError` event and replacing the response body with whatever you'd like.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I put following code OnBeforeReturningError `oSession.responseBodyBytes = new byte[0];` and browser didn't return friendly error message. Do you know why?

Comment: What did you set the response code to? Did you adjust the Content-Length header properly, since you didn't use the utilSetResponseBody method that sets that for you?